# SWIFT 5.1 Mutablecopy

Tags: swift

I wrote this code like this when I logged in, it is ok. but when I run again it is not working at all.
in Xcode Version 11.2.1

**this is my code:**

```swift
var currentUser: NSMutableDictionary?     
// saving logged info here
currentUser = parsedJSON.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableDictionary
UserDefaults.standard.set(currentUser, forKey: "currentUser")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen, what did happen?

Comment: when I run it in Xcode again it likes currentUser was empty.

Comment: Do not use `NS...` mutable collection types in Swift at all. And there is reason to  explicitly save a **mutable** collection type to `UserDefaults`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following way...

// Saving logged info here Userdefault

```
let result = jsonDict["result"] as? NSDictionary ?? [:]

let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: result, requiringSecureCoding: false)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "currentUser")
```

// Get data from Userdefault

```
let result = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "currentUser")
if result != nil{
    let dict = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(result!) as? NSDictionary ?? [:]
    print("Current User Details : - \(dict)")
}
```