# what is the best way to save json in app in iOS?

Tags: swift

I am using a json that is very big. it takes lot of time to fetch it as api response. I want to fetch it once and save it locally, so that I can use it in my app. I want to save it in a file but the question is where should I store this file.

Comment: you can store it in document directory.

Comment: use local database like realm or sqlite. on first launch of app download json and insert it to local database and after that access it from local database

Comment: i think UserDefault check this link my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59170370/6920041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it as a text file inside your app directory

```
let file = "jsonResponse.txt"

let text = "<Json String>"




func writeFile(text : String){

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

        //writing
        do {
            try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        catch {}


    }
}


func readFile() -> Sting{

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

        //reading
    do {
        let text2 = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)

        return text2
    }
    catch {}
    }

    return ""


}
```

simply call writeFile and ReadFile Functions accordingly

Comment: Your welcome man :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do in this kind of situation.

First I run API's on postman and copy `JSON` and paste it to [here](http://jsoncafe.com/). Then give an object name and select code template as `swifty JSON` because you can use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) which makes it very easy to handle your `JSON` object. Now you can download all the class files and add it to your project. then you need to create new file which will handle the process of storing and fetching your `JSON` file to document directory and it will look like:

```
import Foundation

/// `Cacher` is a super simple cross platform solution to persist `Cachable` types into the filesystem.
final public class Cacher {
    /// The path in the filesystem that will hold all the persisted items
    let destination: URL
    private let queue = OperationQueue()

    /// A type for the type of persistance options.
    ///
    /// - temporary: stores `Cachable` types into the temporary folder of the OS.
    /// - atFolder: stores `Cachable` types into a specific folder in the OS.
    public enum CacheDestination {
        /// Stores items in `NSTemporaryDirectory`
        case temporary
        /// Stores items at a specific location
        case atFolder(String)
    }

    // MARK: Initialization

    /// Initializes a newly created `Cacher` instance using the specified storage destination.
    /// *Note* If using `.atFolder(String)` make sure the destination is valid.
    ///
    /// - Parameter destination: path to the location where `Cacher` will persist its `Cachable` items.
    public init(destination: CacheDestination) {
        switch destination {
        case .temporary:
            self.destination = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        case .atFolder(let folder):
            let documentFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            self.destination = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentFolder).appendingPathComponent(folder, isDirectory: true)
        }

        try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: self.destination, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    }

    // MARK

    /// Store a `Cachable` object in the directory selected by this `Cacher` instance.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - item: `Cachable` object to persist in the filesystem
    ///   - completion: callback invoked when the persistance finishes, it will either contain the `URL` of the persisted item, or the `Error` raised while trying to.
    public func persist(item: Cachable, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        var url: URL?
        var error: Error?

        // Create an operation to process the request.
        let operation = BlockOperation {
            do {
                url = try self.persist(data: item.transform(), at: self.destination.appendingPathComponent(item.fileName, isDirectory: false))
            } catch let persistError {
                error = persistError
            }
        }

        // Set the operation's completion block to call the request's completion handler.
        operation.completionBlock = {
            completion(url, error)
        }

        // Add the operation to the queue to start the work.
        queue.addOperation(operation)
    }

    /// Load cached data from the directory
    ///
    /// - Parameter fileName: of the cached data stored in the file system
    /// - Returns: the decoded cached data (if any)
    public func load<T: Cachable & Codable>(fileName: String) -> T? {
        guard
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: destination.appendingPathComponent(fileName, isDirectory: false)),
            let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            else { return nil }
        return decoded
    }

    // MARK: Private

    private func persist(data: Data, at url: URL) throws -> URL {
        do {
            try data.write(to: url, options: [.atomicWrite])
            return url
        } catch let error {
            throw error
        }
    }
}

/// A type that can persist itself into the filesystem.
public protocol Cachable {
    /// The item's name in the filesystem.
    var fileName: String { get }

    /// Returns a `Data` encoded representation of the item.
    ///
    /// - Returns: `Data` representation of the item.
    func transform() -> Data
}

extension Cachable where Self: Codable {
    public func transform() -> Data {
        do {
            let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
            return encoded
        } catch let error {
            fatalError("Unable to encode object: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Also create one more struct:

```
struct CachableObject: Cachable, Codable {

    let fileName: String
    let value: JSON
}
```

Now this `struct` will be needed to store and fetch data.

When you got the data from server you can store it in document directory with:

```
let cacher: Cacher = Cacher(destination: .temporary)
let cachableText = CachableObject(fileName: "yourfilename", value: jsonresponse)
cacher.persist(item: cachableText) { url, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Text failed to persist: \(error)")
    } else {
        print("Text persisted in \(String(describing: url))")
    }
}
```

Now it is stored in your document directory.

If you want to fetch the complete JSON again you can do it with:

```
if let data: CachableObject = cacher.load(fileName: "yourfilename") {
    let jsonData = data.value
    self.yourCustomObject = YourCustomObject.init(fromJson: jsonData)
}
```

And you can use this with any number of API's with different file names and you can store complete `JSON` with this.