# How to deal with deprecated function 'unarchiveObject(with:)'?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain, nskeyedunarchiver

Try to implement KeychainWrapper from here: https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper
It is functioning well but in one piece of code I get mistake: "'unarchiveObject(with:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead"

I tried to follow the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982244/how-to-nskeyedunarchiver-unarchiveobject) which seems to be similar but wasn't successful.

The piece of code is here:

```
open func object(forKey key: String, withAccessibility accessibility: KeychainItemAccessibility? = nil) -> NSCoding? {
    guard let keychainData = data(forKey: key, withAccessibility: accessibility) else {
        return nil
    }

    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: keychainData) as? NSCoding
```

[How to NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982244/how-to-nskeyedunarchiver-unarchiveobject)

Here is the updated version:

```
open func object(forKey key: String, withAccessibility accessibility: KeychainItemAccessibility? = nil) -> NSCoding? {
guard let keychainData = data(forKey: key, withAccessibility: accessibility) else {
    return nil
}

let result = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(keychainData) as? NSCoding

return result
```

Comment: Please refer this 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59170370/6920041

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in following way...

```
let result = jsonDict["result"] as? NSDictionary ?? [:]
let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: result, requiringSecureCoding: false)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "currentUser")
```

// Get data from Userdefault

```
let result = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "currentUser")
    if result != nil{
    let dict = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(result!) as? NSDictionary ?? [:]
    print("Current User Details : - \(dict)")
}
```

Comment: unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData soon will be deprecated too, but it still works in Xcode14 + iOS16 with no warnings!

Comment: I'm using Xcode 15 and it's indicating <'unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:) instead>.  What is the replacement to unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData solution?

Comment: @user14341201 you can use this --NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, UserDetails.self], from: savedPeople) as? [UserDetails], your model name change and as per the requirement object change.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hint [Himanshu Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6920041/himanshu-patel) It worked for me. Here is the updated code:

```
open func object(forKey key: String, withAccessibility accessibility: KeychainItemAccessibility? = nil) -> NSCoding? {
    guard let keychainData = data(forKey: key, withAccessibility: accessibility) else {
        return nil
    }

    let result = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(keychainData) as? NSCoding

    return result
```

Comment: welcome bro please upvote my answer.

Comment: Himanshu Patel I can't upvote your comment. Please write a short answer and I would be happy to upvote it.

Comment: this is my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59170370/6920041

Comment: Yes, but you posted it not by me :) I can upvote only answers to my questions. :)